# What roles would the hierachy of a private army play in defending a town's sovereignty?

Tags: cities, modern, governance, military-organisation

I have a town where a small private army of about 100 men (breakdown below) looks after its defense and is consulted on any major decisions concerning the town by other local groups that reside in the town. Most of the time the highest ranked guy (let's call him the General) usually makes most of these decisions but may choose to consult with either his direct subordinates or the leaders of the local groups. To clarify, this is not a totalitarian regime or anything like that, this structure is simply in place because the town itself doesn't have the resources to defend itself.

During a combat situation, where the safety of the town is at stake, I am wondering what roles the various chains of command would take to play their part.

The command structure hierarchy is as follows (my understanding is that it is similar to a US Marines Platoon):

General

- Major (General's direct subordinate)
- 3 Lieutenants (Each look after 1 platoon of 36 men & 3 Sergeants)
- 9 Sergeants (Each look after 1 squad of 12 men)
- 27 Fireteams (Each with a team leader and 3 other men)

So as a very simple diagram, below the General and major it would look like this:

[image]

So my question is, if there was a threat that required this entire private army to be involved what roles would the different levels of the hierarchy realistically play? My understanding is the General would be making the decisions but how about everyone else, would they all be sent into battle or would for example Lieutenants and above all be cozy in a room somewhere strategizing? The assumption is that everyone has some kind of comms equipment that allows them to communicate with one another in real time.

Comment: "What roles would the different levels of the hierarchy realistically play" depends very very much on what this mercenary company actually does. Who is the enemy? What are the capabilities of the enemy and what are the capabilities of this company? Do they fight on foot with pointed sticks, do they have cannon, rifles, tanks, rockets? What are the intentions of the enemy? What kind of world is this where a company of 100 men can seriously hope to defend the sovereigny of a sovereign power? (For reference, the city-state of Athens fielded 10,000 men at Marathon in 490 BCE, 2500 years ago.)

Comment: If the town doesn't have the resources to defend itself, how is the private army supported?

Comment: What kind of private army is this? Mercenaries (hired, loyal only to money), a private army raised by one of the city rulers, or something else? What is the role of civilians when it comes to decision making (can the General decide everything on their own or do they need to seek approval from city authorities)?

Comment: A sovereign "town" that has the need and ability to defend itself from external military power might be better described as a city-state.

Comment: @AlexP apologies I thought this would be obvious from my explanation, but basically they are a modern private army with structure and ranks similar to US Marines so I would say they function and have at their disposal anything former US Marines that have gone private can realistically get their hands on. I'm not expert, but I would assume that would include handguns, assault rifles, SMGs, LMGs, explosives (C4/grenades) and possibly weapons similar to RPGs and grenade launchers? Happy to get clarification on this.

Comment: @StarfishPrime private mercenary type contracts perhaps? So while part of the team goes in missions the remainder stays at home to defend. If a serious threat happens at home, everyone stays home until it is resolved? Just my stab in the dark, happy to clarification on the realism.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Each role would have a distinct purpose.

## The general will strategize

This is probably a person who has contact with the elites/ nobles. They arranged the contract for the mercenaries, and they have contact with money lenders and banks which fund the troops. They probably have a good amount of military experience, and a lot of contacts to get the goods they need. Their role will be to set broad strategic goals, and negotiate with important people. They are probably the one who met with the head of the town and agreed on a price.

They'll guide the army as to how long it fights, what extra resources it can get, and how aggressive it can be. They probably have a lot of work negotiating other contracts, so they'll not be especially available.

## The major will do tactics.

They are probably also a well experienced person with good writing and speaking skills. They'll coordinate with the town and any local militias to set up defenses. They'll plan the general order of defense- where to set up fortifications, where troops should go, what weapons people should carry.

They'll mostly be away from the troops. No doubt they'll meet them, but their big goal is to plan the overall picture. They need to make sure their troops aren't over-extended, that all the supply chains are functional, that the locals are supporting them appropriately. They don't have time to manage the nitty gritty of the troops.

## The lieutenants and sergeants make sure the troops are ready.

Lietenants are assistants to captains (or majors), and are there to translate the grand ideas of the major to the ground. The sergeants are leaders of the privates, and are there to get the privates to do what they're told. They both have to be in battle a lot.

Lieutenants will be more likely to be sitting in a smokey room with the major and some town leaders planning out the town's defense, but they'll also spend time with the troops. They'll tend to be more educated formally so they can better interact with the elite, but are often less experienced militarily.

Sergeants won't normally be in the smokey rooms, but they're the workhorses of the platoon. They make sure all the nitty gritty gets managed from the ground, and normally have a good amount of military experience. They should know all their men, and keep equipment, morale, health and training up to date. They are more rough and ready, and likely to offend polite society. That said, they interact a lot with lieutenants, so they're exposed to the upper echelons of the platoon.

Both might well be sent into battle, and both are likely targets of assassins and killers.

## Team leaders are potential backup leaders.

These are generally soldiers who seem a bit sharper and more coordinated than others. They might be promoted to be sergeants if needed, or if enough of them die in the field. They generally don't have a great deal of skilled writing, connections, or experience but they're the most together of a small group.

All of these things could change depending on the platoon. It's a big morale boost to have the major fight with you, and some ranks are more loose than others, and the company could be more or less experienced.

## Knowledge matters and creates alternate hierarchies.

Engineers and experts in explosives and communications will have their own masteries. A private might be in the smokey room if they're the person who understands communications science enough to pierce enemy jamming, or if they can build bridges that get you where you need to be.

Comment: Very helpful breakdown, thank you so much! I may have missed it but I couldn't help but feel that the explanation was more focused on how these roles function during preparation for battle. Would it be possible for you to add what they do during battle also please? Eg. would the roles you mentioned in the smokey rooms stay in smokey rooms together or some take up positions in the field? Also, if a significant number of the fireteams are is "disabled" would roles such as sergeants and even lieutenants take up front line roles if they feel this would allow them to win?

Comment: Sergeants and lieutenants both have to be on the front line. They are there to manage the troops in different ways and so both have to fight. The lieutenant attends the prefight smokey room meetings, and represent the interests of the major in the fight, while the sergeant spends their time with the troops, and represents their interests. 

But yeah, they need to be on the field to ensure that the soldiers actually fight and don't just hide in a defensible position and drink whiskey and smoke cigars.

Comment: Nepene Nep, with the comms team relaying information between the general and the ground troops, would they ever be making any decisions and communicating these to the ground troop leaders? I am thinking if for example the general couldn't be reached briefly or something urgent was happening that required immediate action would the comms team ever contact the troop leaders directly instead of always relying on the general to relay it down the chain of command? I am assuming in the troops minds, any communication from the general would override any communication from the comms team?

Comment: Every fire team, squad and platoon will probably have their own radio channel, so the central communication can direct a message to a group if needed. The general could of course tell individual fireteams what to do, but that would be micromanagement, and might well disrupt teams. The traditional thing would be for him to tell the lieutenants what their orders are in broad terms, such as when they ask for some air support, to say "The air over port is too hot but we’re sending a TV danger close on the tank engage suppression.”

Comment: to tell them to keep the enemy tank suppressed by shooting them a lot while they sent a TV missile to take out the tank, because the enemy anti air was too hot to risk their only helicopter. Some generals do micromanage, and it could be needed if they have dead or incompetent lieutenants, but the traditional route would just to be to tell their subordinates. They don't actually know what is going on in the ground in detail. If they need to bypass the chain of command to send an order, they'll likely just tell the entire squad/ platoon.

Answer (score 3):

### Everyone on your table is a combatant... but you need more non-combatants.

Platoon leaders lead thier platoons from the battlefield, not a command tent. It is not until you scale up the a Company sized force (typically about 100-250 men)  that you start to see a sperate command structure from the actual people on the battlefield.

That said, there are people NOT on this table who should be supporting your platoons from the backline.

So, your "General" should be making major strategic calls, and your "major" should be there to give orders in his absence or responding to overflow issues when the general becomes inundated. But these 2 men will hopefully not be your whole non-combatant infrastructure. On top of this you should also have a Gunnery Sergeant who manages the Company's logistics as well as 1-4 other NCOs who perform radio operations and/or administrative assistant duties for a total command room staff of 4-7 men.

Since your private army does not have the benefit of additional specialized units to lean into, you will also need to attach several other non-combatant personnel to this company like mechanics and machinists to maintain the vehicles and equipment, medics for tending the wounded, and logistics personnel for loading and driving supply vehicles, etc. A company this size needs 7-8 medics, and the number of other support personnel will depend heavily on how much weapons and vehicles your company maintains, and how long and vulnerable your supply lines are. If we assume that is is a mostly defensive infantry force, then your need for logistics and mechanical specialists will be relatively low.

So while all 100 people on your table should be on the battlefield, it would not be unreasonable for you to have an additional 30+ men not listed here that are non-combatant members of your private defense force.  MUCH more if you have tanks, gunboats, aircraft, or artillery to support.

**What are your actual Platoon, Squad, and Fire Team leaders doing?**

Your Platoon Leaders are Lieutenants: commissioned officers trained in battlefield tactics. While it is their responsibility to follow orders coming from the company commander (aka:general), they are also expected to understand tactics well enough to decide how best those orders should be carried out based on what they can see with thier own eyes to be true.  If their orders are to take control of a bunker, they figure out how exactly the platoon should maneuver to make it happen... so they are on the actual battlefield, but mostly not fighting.

Squad Leaders are Sergeants: non-commissioned officers.  They are experienced soldiers, but not formally trained in battlefield tactics like a commissioned officer is.  Their roll is mostly to server as a middle-man between the guys giving orders, and the people who need to receive them.

Fire Team leaders could be any rank of enlisted person, and are by-in-large indistinguishable from actual infantry.  When the shooting starts, they join in.  Formally they don't do a whole lot of real leading, but when squad looses cohesion or has to spread out a lot to cover more area, these are the guys the other grunts will turn to for judgement calls.

Comment: Very insightful, thank you very much. Pardon my ignorance, but for the NCOs (non commissioned officers I'm guessing?) doing the comms, would these be of a particular rank usually or do ranks apply to them differently?

Comment: @FrontEnd NCO ranks are not the same in every country/branch of military, but they  typically refer to the enlisted ranks of either Corporal (E-4) or Sergeant (E-5) and up. It is also not strictly necessary that they all even be as high as NCOs, but since this company has a more complex support infrastructure than a more specialized company that works as part of a larger military, I would assume these positions would  be filled by people who need the extra training. IRL, these supplemental command room personal can be anything from E-1 to E-5 depending on the needs of the company.

Comment: Ok thank you for that

Comment: Nosajimiki, with the Gunnery Sergeant (or person looking after logistics) I can understand the prep work they would to prior, but exactly would they be doing during the battle? For example would they be coordinating ammo resupply to the troops, and if so how would they know when troops are running low etc?

Also clarifying, for the comms team would they ever be making any decisions if for example there was limited time to communicate urgent events/escalations to the general? Or would they only ever be allowed to rely information but take no action?

Comment: @FrontEnd Most militaries throughout history do not send logistics personnel into battle even if it means them sitting on their butt during a fight.  Loosing key personnel during a battle is far worse than having a couple less combatants.  Win or loose, your men will still need effective logistics after a battle just as much as they do before; so, if your Gunnery Sergeant is involved in the battle itself, it means things have become very dire.

Comment: Oh ok, so if the Gunnery Sergeant doesn't look after resupply of ammo etc, what do the troops do when running low? Is there someone else they can ask or simply have to make do with what they've got?

Answer (score 3):

In an actual *combat* situation, the tasks that the different ranks are doing will depend very strongly on how well things are going. If everything has gone well, it will be something like this:

- The general, having made the plan, will be with the leaders of the town, reassuring them that everything is going to be fine.
- The major will be at the command post, with the maps and any other sources of information.
- The three lieutenants will be with their platoons, but those platoons will be doing different things:

1. The platoon that is best at scouting and sniping will be in intermittent contact with the approaching enemy, falling back to lead them into the ambush. This is the platoon that needs the smartest sergeants and the most sensible soldiers, because they'll have to take decisions for themselves, and this kind of retreat is tricky.
2. The platoon that has the most aggressive lieutenant will be the ambush, and is waiting for the enemy to advance into the killing zone.
3. The platoon with the most experienced lieutenant is the reserve. They are ready to move and join in the ambush, or to react to an unexpected threat from a different direction. They may be near the command post, or if the general and major are really confident that the enemy can't eavesdrop or interrupt their communications, they may be somewhere else.

An important part of the major's work of the last year or two has been in setting up the platoons and squads for their various foreseeable roles, without making them so specialised that they can't do other things. As the company commander, that's part of his job, and he has to do it without being obvious, because it involves thinking of soldiers as if they were pieces in a game, rather than human beings.

If things have gone really badly, at least one of the platoons is in totally the wrong place and can't contribute. The lieutenants don't know what's going on and are panicking, the sergeants are busy trying to calm them down, and the enemy are bypassing the platoons and advancing on the town.

The reality is always somewhere between these extremes.

Comment: Good to know, thank you very much

Answer (score 2):

The fact that this is a private army seems relevant to your question.
In any army, you have the people at the very top, who are mostly responsible for strategic decisions, and the further down you get in the hierarchy, the more it's tactics.
That means: On the top, the general makes plans. Further down, they are executed.
Von Moltke said something along the lines of "no plan survives the first enemy contact". This means, as soon as things get messy, the officers and sergeants are in change, making tactical decisions that (hopefully) follow the general strategy.
This also means that the work of the general is mostly done well before the battle. In the battle itself, it's officers, sergeants and soldiers, showing whether or not the general did a good job.

Comment: Ok sure those are really good points for me to consider. Thank you

Comment: Also, the style of the army makes a difference. A mercenary army will operate with a looser style while the German army in WWII needed to go all the way up the chain in order to respond on D-Day.

Answer (score 0):

**Everyone in this is tactical leadership**. 100 men is *nothing* in military terms. This is like, 1 company, & a smaller one at that. Normally you have to hit battalion, which is more than 500 people to hit people not very close to the fighting, & that is still tactical level. To get to operational & strategic levels your gonna have to go into the 1,000s or 10,000s. 100 is very small in military terms & isn't going to be large enough to be much beyond a small combat unit.